# pip for python3.7 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to install pip for python 3.7. When I tried to search online, one solution I found was to install pip using get-pip.py. However, it's failing for me:

```
sudo python3.7 get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21373, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/download.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp3273u8va/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/glibc.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Now, to resolve this, I found that `libffi-dev` package should be installed. However, I verified that this package is already installed on my system. I am not sure how should I resolve this. Can someone please help?

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

Update:
I followed the steps to install Python 3.7 from https://serverfault.com/questions/918335/best-way-to-run-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-which-comes-with-python-3-5.  Also, When I check for pip3.7 installation, I am getting the output as

```
$ pip3.7 --version
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

But when I execute my program, I get an error like `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip`.

Comment: How did you get python 3.7? If you installed from python.org then you already have pip.

Comment: Updated question to include more details for the context you asked. Please see the update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it's a lot simpler.
Assuming your Linux is Debian-based (for exaxample, Ubuntu), you should install pip with `sudo apt install python3-pip` for Python 3.x as you wish, or with `sudo apt install python-pip` for Python 2.x.

If your OS is not debian based, just change the package manager in use (for example use yum or pacman instead of apt).

[Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver), you can also find a guide for installing pip on Ubuntu 18.04.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I tried. I have updated my question with more details. It looks like I have pip installed, but python3.7 isn't able to link to it.

Comment: Open a terminal & run `sudo apt install python3-pip`. Does it return `python-pip is already the newest version`? If not, that is your problem. The answer from the ServerFault community question you posted doesn't install python3--pip ..

Comment: Yes exactly, it returns ```python3-pip is already the newest version```. But my problem is that python3.7 is not able to recognize the pip and throws an error as stated in mine update.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Let's try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3.7 python3-pip`.

Comment: I am sorry, it could be a silly question. When I am trying to reinstall python3.7, it says ```
E: Unable to locate package python3.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7'
```. 
Do I need to update the repo first?

Comment: What OS are you currently using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187826/discussion-between-nick-tritsis-and-apoorv-gupta).

Comment: So, Nick suggested reinstalling python3.7 from the package(serverfault link) I used. When I reinstalled it, it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I installed `python3.7` in Ubuntu 16.04 via `ppa` (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`) (See [detailed instructions ppa installation Python3.7](https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04))

For me, Nick Tritsis answer did not work. The only way to install `pip` was directly downloading the file [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and running it on python 3.7 (according to the [method in the official site](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line))

```
python3.7 get-pip.py
```

However, as I did so I got an error message

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an 
EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

One **not recommended** solution is to use `sudo`:

```
sudo python3.7 get-pip.py
```

### Recommended Solution

One can just supply the argument `--user` when calling the script like so:

```
  python3.7 get-pip.py --user
```

credits to @Matthew Strasiotto, who suggested me this solution.

### Alternative Solution

This alternative solution is for fun; it is more complicated than the recommended: We can add the option `--user` into the file.

So we open the file `get-pip.py`and we change the code line where the command arguments are given: we added there the argument `--user` that makes installation possible.

Original line:

```
# Add our default arguments
 args = ["install", "--upgrade", "--force-reinstall"] + args
```

Modified line:

```
# Add our default arguments
args = ["install", "--user", "--upgrade", "--force-reinstall"] + args
```

After this modification `python3.7 get-pip.py` runs smooth.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, thanks for posting!

Comment: this did not work for me. I get this error (its the same error if I use without the --user parameter ):   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f871bcaa810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip

Comment: Note: Iam on Ubuntu 16.04 behind a corporate proxy  ... will greatly appreciate any help. Spent enormous amount of time already on what should be a trivial thing. But then this is the world of linux. Pain is the default setting

Comment: @objectNotFound the error sounds heavy. If it is about the `connection`, it may have nothing to do with the `--user` folder, but rather with your internet (may be firewall?)—just pure guessing. I'll pray for you, it is the only thing I can do; please report any success.

Comment: connection is not the issue as apt pkg manager is able to download from internet. Anyone got around that issue using this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/880147/1100134 but now I have new problem ... cannot install pywinrm using the same method ( i.e downloading the tar file , extracting and running setup.py ) ... as I said Pain comes standard and compulsory in linux world. Quite possibly the worst OS platform out there. Anyways thanks for your help/prayers.

Comment: the get-pip url is no longer maintained, you might try this url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`